# Accidentally Deleted bootentry

Tags: efibootmgr

I've accidentally deleted the first two boot entries and they were of bios setup and multiboot menu. My laptop is lenovo z570 ideapad and installed Ubuntu on it . It's directly booting to Ubuntu even if I'm pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>.

I did this using `efibootmgr`.

My virtualization is disabled in bios and wine is not opening flash software. So, virtual box is not booting windows in Ubuntu.